# Difference tool QGIS shows too many Differences

Tags: qgis, error, overlay, differences

After running QGIS Difference Tool, I get a lot of differences, but I don't know where they are coming from. The input files are almost similar...

Input Image (overlay input almost the same, but from different years with one or two different polygons):

[image: Input Image]

Difference Output:

[image: Difference Output]

Comment: i realized though, that some of the vertexes are not connected to each other? might this be the problem? is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe first perform a topology check and then fix.

Comment: @annchi usually, it is the first reason of that.